# C++: what are the most common vulnerabilities and how to avoid them?

Tags: c++

As I code, I try to be security-conscious all the time. The problem is that I need to know what to look for and what to prevent.

Is there a list somewhere of the most common (C++) software vulnerabilities and how to avoid them?

What about C++ software for specific uses, e.g. a linux console software or a web application?

Comment: code does not compile is the most common one :)

Comment: I would have thought you code not compiling would have been one of the best way to prevent vulnerabilities getting shipped.

Comment: I'd agree, no executable - no security holes. Static code checking in languages like C++ is very difficult, if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many resources are available, some in question are:

- [SEI CERT C++ Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682)
- [SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard)
- The more language-agnostic [Writing Secure Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228) book from Microsoft Press (funny, I know)
- David Wheeler's [Secure Programming in Linux/Unix](https://dwheeler.com/secure-programs/)

Answer (score 5):

This site may have links to what you are looking for:

http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Programming/C/CSecurity/tabid/1549/Default.aspx

---

I guess I'll add that one of the most common problems in C and C++ is buffer overflow:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Use_of_safe_libraries

For that, use only functions that check boundaries, like `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: `strncpy` is a *bad* idea because it can leave you without null-terminated strings, leading to even worse buffer overflows. Alternatives like `strlcpy`, `strcpy_s`, and `memcpy` are better.

Answer (score 2):

There are also problems such as 
1. Segmentation Fault
2. Memory Leak
3. Memory Allocation errors, etc
that might be of your concern...